# What is a semi-open Jordan Curve?

Tags: real-analysis, curves

Has **anyone** heard the term before? I am reading a paper by E. Hopf written in 1950 which states the following:

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$. Denote by $p$ a point in $\mathbb{R^n}$. A closed subset of the boundary of $\Omega$ is called *accessible from within $\Omega$* if $\Omega$ contains a semi-open Jordan curve $p(t), 0\leq t < \infty$ whose points of accumulation, for $t\rightarrow \infty$, precisely constitute that boundary part.

The language used by Hopf has stumped me. I think a semi-open Jordan curve refers to a curve which gets "arbitrarily close to being closed" but isn't quite. Ie, a curve $p(t)$ which at $p(0)$ is at a  point $x$ and as $t$ rushes off to infinity, the curve $p(t)$ keeps getting closer to $x$ but never reaches $x$. However, if someone knows a rigorous definition, it would help a lot.

Comment: It means the same as semi-open interval $[0,\infty)$ or $[0,1)$, closed on one end but not the other.

Comment: Here is a link to the paper. If someone has time to analyse the argument, you could deduce what it means. 

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1950-001-01/S0002-9939-1950-0033019-1/S0002-9939-1950-0033019-1.pdf

Comment: From scanning the argument, I tend to believe the curve does not return to $x$ necessarily. I don't believe the it will be a simple closed curve. For example, I believe the entire boundary of the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is accessible y taking a spiral which accumulates on the entire boundary.

Comment: Especially the condition that the points of accumulation are PRECISELY the boundary suggests it does not contain $x$ which is not a boundary point.

Answer (score 2):

In context, the obvious guess would be that "semi-open Jordan curve" refers to a continuous injection from a half-open interval, in this case the interval $[0,\infty)$.  (Or maybe not just a continuous injection but an embeddding, but that makes no difference since the condition that the accumulation points as $t\to\infty$ are all on the boundary makes it automatically an embedding.)

Comment: After some deliberation, this seems to me like the most likely scenario.